# C# - How to Italicise a words within a string resource

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I'm writing a WPF application and I need to italicise words within descriptions on my view while still having them within resources to provide multi-lingual support later on. These descriptions are resourced and pass through a director that matches the descriptions in the view model by their code to their appropriate placement.

What I have tried:

I've begun resourcing the words of importance separately and added placeholder codes within the description resources. I then wanted to insert the words of importance into the description strings as they pass through the director but I can't italicise them at this stage either as they're just strings! How can i do achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically a case where you are intertwining your data with the view of your data. You should keep them separated, as [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) advises.

You have some data that consists of two parts:

- your description
- the texts within your description that needs to be emphasized

This data can be displayed on several ways. One way - the method you want - is to display the complete description while the texts that need to be emphasized must be shown in italics.

But one could also think of a viewing method where the emphasized words are shown in bold fond, or a different font, or in red, or upside down.

By separating your data from the way you view your data, it is possible to change this view without having to change the data itself

Now back to your question. So you have some text, and some subtext that need to be emphasized. How you know which text needs to be emphasized is out of scope of your question. How you put this information inside this class is also out-of-scope of this question. All you need is some translate function that will translate your text into a format that allows interpreters of the translated text to know the complete text, and which phrases must be emphasized.

How to mark where the emphasize starts and where it stops is not really important, just use some well-defined method.

For instance, you could use the HTML method for emphasis:

```
Some normal text <em>is emphasized</em> and normal again
```

If you want, you could use any other method, like adding double forward slashes to switch emphasizing on or off, or anything else. It doesn't matter, as long as it is well defined.

So the class that holds your text and your emphasized needs a procedure to extract the translated text

```
public string ExtractTranslatedText()
{
    // TODO: take your original text and add <em> and </em>
    // to mark begin and end of emphasis
}
```

It seems that you almost succeeded creating this function.

Now once you've got a string that holds this emphases, you need to display it. It depends on your display class how this can be done.

Suppose you want to display it italicized in a RichTextBox. You could derive your class from RichTextBox, or you could create an extension function for RichTextBox.

See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static class RichTestBoxExtensions
{
    // TODO: add the required functions
}
```

We need a function that will append some text to the already existing text in the text box in a given System.Drawing.FontStyle:

```
public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, FontStyle fontStyle)
{
    box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;

    Font savedSelectionFont = box.SelectionFont;
    box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, fontStyle);
    box.AppendText(text);
    box.SelectionFont = savedSelectionFont;
}
```

If you want, you could also add methods to show the text in a different color.
The code will be very similar.

Now you need to put your translated string with emphasis markers in the rich text box

```
public static ShowEmphasis(this RichTextBox, string text, FontStyle emphasisStyle)
{
    const string emphasisOn = "<em>";
    const string emphasisOff = "</em>";

    while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {   // still some text to print
        // get the substring until first emphasisOn
        int indexStartEmphasis = text.Index(emphasisOn);

        if (indexStartEmphasis == -1)
        {   // no emphasisOn anymore: write all in emphasisStyle
            richTextBox.AppendText(text, emphasisStyle);
            text = String.Empty; // no text left
        }
        else
        {   // write until emphasisOn:
            string normalText = text.SubString(0, indexStartEmphasis);
            richTextBox.AppendText(normalText, FontStyle.Normal);

            // remove the normalText + <em> from text:
            text = text.Substring(indexStartEmphasis + emphasisOn.Length);

            // do the same until emphasisOff
            int indexStopEmphasis = text.Index(emphasisOff);
            if (indexStopEmphasis == -1)
            {   // no emphasisOff anymore: write all in emphasisStyle
                richTextBox.AppendText(text, FontStyle.Normal);
                text = String.Empty; // no text left
            }
            else
            {   // write until emphasisOff in emphasisStyle:
                string emphasizedText = text.SubString(0, indexStopEmphasis);
                richTextBox.AppendText(emphasizedText, emphasisStyle);

                // remove the emphasizedlText + </em> from text:
                text = text.Substring(indexStopEmphasis + emphasisOff.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your well thought out answer, I'll be attempting to use the MVC format from now on as I can see a lot of issues with my current design. Thank you also for the pointer to Extension methods I found that very useful too.

Answer (score 0):

If your resources will be consumed by a TextBlock you have to separate the text into separate inlines.

E.g.:
The text you want to show is `This is an italic, bold and underlinded text`.
This string need to be split up into separate parts for your resource file like the following:

- Res1: This is an
- Res2: italic
- Res3: ,
- Res4: bold
- Res5: and
- Res6: underlined
- Res7: text

Your XAML then should look like the following:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14">
    <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Res1}" />
    <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Res2}" FontStyle="Italic" />
    <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Res3}" />
    <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Res4}" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Res5}" />
    <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Res6}" TextDecorations="Underline" />
    <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Res7}" />
</TextBlock>
```

This results in the following format:

[image]

Comment: Your answer was very valuable, however if I can avoid using the second resource it would be much handier.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an entire description as one `string` presented in f.e. a label, and you only want one part of this `string` italic, then this is not possible.

In case of a `label` (not sure what `control` is presenting your descriptions) you can create a seperated `label` for this important word, and place this specific `label` (with the italic property set) where you want it to be.